# I have a problem with 2 Classes to create element on page and display it

Tags: javascript

So I made 2 classes,first is the create element one:

```js
class CElement {
    constructor(value,elementType,elementStyle){
        this.element = document.createElement(elementType);
        this.element.innerHTML = value;
        this.element.style = elementStyle;
    }

    display(displayTo) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(displayTo).appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

The second is the create mob and diplay to:

```js
class Mob {
    constructor(level) {
        this.mobLvl = level;
    }

    display(elementClass) {
        ele = new CElement(this.mobLvl + "<br>",'p',"color:red;");
        ele.display(elementId);
    }
}
```

I checked my code online for syntax errors , and I don't have any?????
So why doesn't it work when I call:

```js
var mob = new Mob(1,"div","color:red;");
mob.display("someClassName");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your code:

1. You forgot `this` in the `display()` function.
2. `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array, so you can't use `appendChild()` directly, you have to loop over your array or use another selector, for example `querySelector()`.
3. `ele` is not defined in your `display()` function.
4. You use `elementClass` as argument of the `display()` function but then use `elementId` inside your function.

Finally, a working version could be something like this, that you can of course adapt to your need:

```js
class CElement {
  constructor(value, elementType, elementStyle) {
    this.element = document.createElement(elementType);
    this.element.innerHTML = value;
    this.element.style = elementStyle;
  }
  display(displayTo) {
 document.querySelector(displayTo).appendChild(this.element);
  }
}

class Mob {
  constructor(level) {
    this.mobLvl = level;
  }
  display(elementClass) {
    var ele = new CElement(this.mobLvl + "<br>", 'p', "color:red;");
    ele.display(elementClass);
  }
}

var mob = new Mob(1, "div", "color:red;");
mob.display(".someClassName");
```

```html
<div class="someClassName"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot the `this.` in your CElement.display function. This makes it so that the element variable is undefined, and thus it doesn't append anything to the document.

Comment: This is one of the problems, but there is a little bit more :)